# Как корректно проверить доступность Интернет?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mobile-development, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

Как корректно проверить доступность сети Интернет в мобильном приложении?

Включен ли доступ в Интернет на телефоне, и, даже если включен, доступна ли сеть (есть возможность загрузить или передать информацию через сеть).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var p = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
if (p != null 
    && p.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() >= NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess) 
{
  // ...
}
```